# IllegalArgumentException: 'Field "label" does not exist. in PYSPARK

Tags: pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I have been developing a function for linear regression in pyspark and validating the accuracy using cross validation . But it throws an error as 'llegalArgumentException: 'Field "label" does not exist.' but i have assigned the response variable to it. Seen few examples in google and observed that it is working for other folks not to me unless i am doing something wrong.

```
Herewith, I have given the code and it would of great help if u can point out my mistake .Thanks in Advance 
# Linear regression - SPARK

# Libraries to be loaded
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator


def spark_linear_regression(dsname, target, ratio):
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('ml-bank').getOrCreate()
    data = spark.read.csv(dsname, header=True, inferSchema=True)
    data = data.dropna()
    print("Completed : 10 % ")

    cat_col = [t[0] for t in data.dtypes if t[1] == 'string']
    indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column + "_index").fit(data) for column in
                cat_col]
    index_colname = [t[0] + "_index" for t in data.dtypes if t[1] == 'string']
    selected_column = list(set(data.columns) - set(cat_col))
    selected_column.extend(index_colname)

    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)
    df_r = pipeline.fit(data).transform(data)
    df_r = df_r.select(selected_column)

    print("Completed : 30 %")

    selected_column.remove(target)
    assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=selected_column, outputCol="features")
    final_data = assembler.transform(df_r)
    final_data = final_data.select(['features', target])

    train_ratio = ratio / 100
    train_ratio = round(train_ratio, 2)
    val_ratio = round(1 - train_ratio, 2)

    train_data, test_data = final_data.randomSplit([train_ratio, val_ratio], seed=500)
    print("Completed : 50 %")
    linear_regression = LinearRegression(featuresCol='features', labelCol=target, maxIter=10)
    param_grid = ParamGridBuilder() \
        .addGrid(linear_regression.regParam, [0.1, 0.01]) \
        .addGrid(linear_regression.fitIntercept, [False, True]) \
        .addGrid(linear_regression.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]) \
        .build()

    linear_regression = CrossValidator(estimator=linear_regression,
                                       estimatorParamMaps=param_grid,
                                       evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(),
                                       numFolds=5)

    print("Completed : 60 %")
    linear_regression_model = linear_regression.fit(train_data)
    linear_regression_summary = linear_regression_model.summary

    print("Completed : 80 %")
    print("Training RMSE: %f" % linear_regression_summary.rootMeanSquaredError)
    print("Training R^2: %f" % linear_regression_summary.r2)

    linear_pred = linear_regression_model.transform(test_data)
    linear_pred.select("prediction", target, "features").show(5)
    linear_evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(predictionCol="prediction",
                                           labelCol=target, metricName="r2")
    print("Completed : 95 %")
    print("R Squared (R2) on test data = %g" % linear_evaluator.evaluate(linear_pred))


spark_linear_regression(Mart_Sales.csv", "Item_MRP",
                        80)
```

Comment: Got it..For CV , we have to rename the target as "LABEL" even inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RegressionEvaluator(metricName="rmse", labelCol = 'resp')
```

to your cross evaluator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).